# How can I make the eth private key generate result in left instead in right side?

Tags: python, replit

Below is my sample code in generating ethereum private key in right side.

```
import pyetherbalance
#from etherscan.accounts import Account
from ethereum import utils
#import os
import time
import secrets
import random
#import sys

dosya4 = open("hacker_address.txt", "r")
start= time.time()
for toplam in range(1234567890):
  zaman = time.time() - start
  h=random.randint(1,10000000)
  
  h1 = h+0
  while (h<=h1):   
    private_key ="{:064x}".format(h)
    raw_address = utils.privtoaddr(private_key)
    
    account_address= (utils.checksum_encode(raw_address)).lower()
    dosya4.seek(0)
    #account_address = "0x267F70f9B856de226FEa5FC1B0a8E319c72CEff5"
    aranan_varmi = dosya4.read().find(account_address)
    infura_url = ''
    balance = pyetherbalance.PyEtherBalance(infura_url)
    balance_eth = balance.get_eth_balance(account_address)
    
    if aranan_varmi != - 1 :
      print("ahaaaaa esleme varrr")
      dosya2 = open("eslesme.txt", "a")
      dosya2.write(private_key+" "+account_address+ "\n")
      dosya2.close()
      print("Private key:"+private_key)
      print("Address:"+account_address)
      time.sleep(5)
    else:
      print (private_key, account_address, balance_eth)
      if balance_eth['balance'] > 0:
        print("EUREKA...EUREKA...EUREKA...")
        print(private_key, account_address, balance_eth,
      file=open("esleme.txt", "a"))
        #sys.exit()

    h=h+1
  #print("***********************************************")
dosya4.close()
print ("toplam zaman %s saniye" % zaman)
```

what I want to achieve is to generate it in left side.
example: 0x7af2cd5900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: i tried this private_key = ((os.urandom(2)).hex())+"000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" and it works, but, is there simple way to do it?

Comment: at least shorter: `…+"0"*60`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way for example

```
magic = "fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd036414"
    while len(magic) < 64:
        magic = magic + "0"
    magic = magic[:64-len(str(hex(z)[2:]))] + str(hex(z)[2:])
    PRIVATE_KEY = str(magic)
```

or this way if using left sequence,where z is the counter:

```
magic = str(hex(z)[2:]) + "fa002a6a5bc0f42cc9a8806ab109bf5cd2f8bb6c54d4"
    while len(magic) < 64:
        magic = "0" + magic
    PRIVATE_KEY = str(magic)
    hdwallet: HDWallet = HDWallet(symbol=SYMBOL)
    hdwallet.from_private_key(private_key=PRIVATE_KEY)
    privatekey = hdwallet.private_key()
    ethaddr = hdwallet.p2pkh_address()
```